# Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-logcat

I have a problem:

**Java Code**

```
public class VisualizzaListaActivity extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DaAcquistareActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("daAcquistare").setIndicator("Da Acquistare").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AcquistatiActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("acquistati").setIndicator("Acquistati").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}

}
```

**XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"   <-------------- It's tabhost -.-"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget
       android:id="@android:id/tabs"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
       android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**And LogCat**

```
12-16 15:26:22.519: E/AndroidRuntime(8262): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.smile.matteo.spesaPRO/android.smile.matteo.spesaPRO.VisualizzaListaActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'             
12-16 15:26:22.519: E/AndroidRuntime(8262): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
12-16 15:26:22.519: E/AndroidRuntime(8262):         at android.smile.matteo.spesaPRO.VisualizzaListaActivity.onCreate(VisualizzaListaActivity.java:13)
```

**Problem**

Someone can tell me why it's says

> Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'

when the android:id = @android:id/tabhost?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the whole project? Sometimes eclipse is a bit buggy in those situations

Comment: try deleting your R file and rebuilding.

Comment: I tried to clean the project, restart it, and delete R but nothing. I have tried to use this code in another application and it's started but in this dont run

Comment: Do you have multiple layout folders? If so, check that every xml layout file have the attribute.

Comment: @LadaRaider Your comment solved my problem! My project uses a library, both had main.xml in layout, and so I got the missing tabhost error. Deleted the main.xml I didn't need and the problem is fixed, thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try cleaning your build from the `Project > Clean...` menu if you are using Eclipse. Sounds simple but often fixes this problem.

Comment: Is your xml file named `main.xml`?

Comment: Change `setContentView(R.layout.main);` to `setContentView(R.layout.visualizzaliste);` but I guess you got that!

Comment: i'm a very big idiot !!! Thanks very much !!! i have concentrated my a attention on the xml file and i don't have see this... Thank you very much yet

Answer (score 20):

I believe the message means this:

```
     <TabHost android:id="@+id/tabhost"
```

should be changed to:

```
     <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
```

Comment: I had to use: android:id="@android:id/tabhost" without the *

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me, because i use TabActivity

Answer (score 2):

Only thing you need to change is android:id attribute in layout xml  , It should be " android:id="@android:id/tabhost"   "

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
Actually I extended `TabActivity` for `DaAcquistareActivity` class. This was the reason. I solved the problem by extending `DaAcquistareActivity` with `Activity` and not with `TabActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution. 
If you're switching to a new Activity check it extends, perhaps on reflex copied from the primary, **and there is a TabActivity**, but we need **Activity or other activity.**